# Why 255 in ip address can't be host address?

Tags: ip-address

Can I have  IP address like this - 145.234.255.255 /12 ?

Host id is 10101111111111111111 (720895) and we see, that all bits are not one, in order to it will be called a broadcast address…

Comment: With an "standard" configuration .255 would be the broadcast IP, that doesn't belong to any host. Check [what it's a broadcast IP](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/broadcast-address/) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407389/can-an-ip-address-end-in-255-and-not-be-a-broadcast-ip-address). Also [this](https://superuser.com/questions/665502/why-cant-ip-addresses-start-with-0-or-255)...

Comment: Definitely NO. Each part of the host's IP address must be between 0 and 254.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, re-reading your question more in-depth your IP `145.234.255.255 /12` it's valid.

That's because with that submask (`255.240.0.0`) the last IP / broadcast IP it's  `145.239.255.255` and the first IP is `145.224.0.0`. As your IP (`145.234.255.255`) it's inside that range it's a valid IP.

I still recommend you [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407389/can-an-ip-address-end-in-255-and-not-be-a-broadcast-ip-address)

Comment: thank you very much.   Your answer clarified the problem....